# Curious about behaving of OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a question why does OCaml behaves somewhat unusual. By defining the function

`let abs_diff x y = abs(x - y);;`

we get `val abs_diff : int -> int -> int = <fun>` now by defining as

`let abs_diff x y =
    fun x -> (fun y -> abs(x - y));;`

`val abs_diff : 'a -> 'b -> int -> int -> int = <fun>`

now using another function called as

`let dist_from3 = abs_diff 3;;`

with the first definition it works perfectly but with the second one it does not work as expected. We get that it is

`val dist_from3 : '_a -> int -> int -> int = <fun>`

why is it behaving like that, and why are those two definition of the at first look same function different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second definition you have two distinct appearances (bindings) of `x` and `y`. That's why there are four parameters in the result. This is what you want:

```
let abs_diff = fun x -> fun y -> abs (x - y)
```

(FWIW in actual practice I sometimes make this mistake, especially when using the `function` keyword.)